# Is it possible to run pacman on a hard drive install of Antergos Linux from a Antergos Linux 'live' usb?

Tags: live-usb, antergos, software-updates

I'm having video issues - When I boot into Antergos I get a movable mouse cursor but no logon 'dialog'. Booting from an Antergos 'live' usb video is fine. Wasn't able to find help specific to my situation using Google (quite possibly I don't know how to ask the question 'correctly' for Google to find it), so was hoping I could run 'Software Update' from the 'live' usb, but 'point it at' the Antergos installed on the hard drive instead of the usb. I don't know if that is even possible, tried searching on Google for a solution, but again, it is quite possible I am not wording my question correctly for Google to find relevant web results.

Specifically, my question is: is using a Antergos 'live' usb to do a 'Software Update' of a hard drive install of Antergos possible, and if it is, how do I do it.

By the way this is on a laptop using Intel's 'built-in' graphics support - no discrete video chip/card and had been working fine for a while, this is not a new install. I assume the last time I booted into Antergos and ran the 'Software Update' it updated some package that wasn't quite ready for 'prime time'.

Comment: `pacman --root /mnt/harddriveroot -Syu`

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the Arch Linux live ISO [here](https://www.archlinux.org/download/)
2. Flash it to your flash drive
3. Start up your computer off of the Arch Linux drive
4. Mount the hard drive home partition to `/mnt`.

   - Run `lsblk` to see what your partitions are called. Here is an example output:

   sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk
   ├─sda1   8:1    0   511M  0 part
   ├─sda2   8:2    0 289.6G  0 part
   ├─sda3   8:3    0     8G  0 part
   └─sda4   8:4    0  1007K  0 part

   Usually, the largest partition is your root partition. (In my case, `/dev/sda2`)

   - Run `mount <partition> /mnt`. In my case, `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
5. Mount the hard drive boot partition (if you have one) and all other partitions in their respective place, but based on `/mnt`. For example your boot partition (in my case, `/dev/sda1`. The root partition is usually 250-500 MB in size) gets mounted to `/mnt/boot`.
6. Run the command `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash`
7. You are now running "inside" your hard drive Antergos installation. Run the command `pacman -Syu` to update all software installed on it.
8. When it finishes press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to exit the chroot and then type `systemctl reboot` to restart your computer. When it reaches the BIOS boot screen, remove the flash drive to start up from your hard drive.